# create new template like toString() in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I need a code snippet that have to print all the properties and their values like how **toString()** works. But i dont know how to create a template for this in eclipse.

Can any one please help.

Note: I want to do this only with template only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very free-form question; if you want to do it from within the IDE, you will need to write your own plug-in (because the template support is there, but isn't flexible enough). If you can do it at runtime, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133660/recursive-beanutils-describe).

Comment: Actually i want to create template that prints the property and their value i dont know how to achieve this

Comment: See the link I gave you, the accepted answer has most of the code.