# How to check if all non-primitive elements in object is null

Tags: java

Is there any shortcut for checking if an objects all elements(and also their elements) are null. For example I want to check If a country object(and its city and its street) is null or not? I don't want to check them one by one like;

```
country == null || country.city == null || country.city.street == null


public class Country{

  City city;
  ....

}

public class City{

  Street street;
  ....
}

public class Street{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Use `==` operator. Precisely `something == null`

Comment: No, there's no shortcut. It's your job to implement this logic.

Comment: May be you have to write your own method to check all and return true/false accordingly.

Comment: @kocko No, a `String` which _is_ an `Object` - a non-primitive variable _can_ be `null`.

Comment: @ambigram_maker, I'm still sleepy, sorry. :)

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)

Comment: What you are facing is basically the thing why there's something as constructors - to ensure a set of assumptions on your data, e.g. that some fields are not null. If you don't want to enforce given fields through a constructor, you have to cope with this generic data container and check everything by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut: you have to browse recursively your instances and check their fields. You could use a custom version of the browser shown  in [How to list all properties exposed by a Java class and its ancestors in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200676/recursively-list-all-properties-exposed-by-a-class/22201894#22201894). Anyway that approach would make sense if you are working with esoteric legacy code, whereas if you are writing new classes is better enforce all not-nulls in constructor of factory methods.

Comment: You have to browse recursively? I'd think when you have to do that, the answer is already clear - not all contained references are null.

Comment: they could be null on the second level, and so on :)

Comment: But then the object you started with must have had at least one  non-null reference, and so the check can return false.