# How to get methods inside a class

Tags: java

So I'm working on a plugin loader for a game and what it does is load plugins (`class` objects) from a `.jar` inside a folder, then add them to an `ArrayList` (so users can make their own mods). But my java experience isn't the best :/ So far it gets the classes in the `jar` but I need to check what methods are in the class (such as the constructor for labeling). Or if someone knows a better way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

`Plugin.java`:

```
package me.rigamortis.faurax.plugin;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import me.rigamortis.faurax.core.Core;

public class Plugin {

    public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
    final File folder = new File(mc.mcDataDir + File.separator + "Faurax/Plugins");
    public String jar;
    public static String className;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private int color;
    private int key;

    public Plugin() {
        if(!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();

        loadPlugins(folder);

        if(folder != null)
            getClassNames(folder);
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public void setDesc(String newDesc) {
        desc = newDesc;
    }

    public void setColor(int newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }

    public void setKey(int newKey) {
        key = newKey;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    /**
     * A hook for plugins
     */
    public void onTick() {}

    public void loadPlugins(final File folder) {
        try{
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                if ( !fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    if(fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".jar")){
                        jar = fileEntry.getName();
                        Core.logNormal("Loading " + fileEntry.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Core.logError("Error? jar isin't a plugin.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getClassNames(final File dir) {
        try{
            ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(dir + File.seperator + jar));
            for(ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry =     zip.getNextEntry())
                if(entry.getName().endsWith(".class") && !entry.isDirectory()) {
                    Core.logNormal("Found "+entry);
                    className = entry.toString();
                }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`PluginLoader.java`:

```
package me.rigamortis.faurax.plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import me.rigamortis.faurax.core.Core;

public class PluginLoader {

    public static List<Plugin> plugins = new ArrayList<Plugin>();

    public PluginLoader() {
        loadPlugins();
    }

    public void loadPlugins() {}

}
```

Comment: Use __reflection__!!!~ Or you can instruct the program to remember the methods anyway, since they're not going to be changed. By the way, why are you trying to build a Minecraft plugin without using Bukkit?

Comment: Making a modded griefing client :P Ill check out reflection though. Quite new to java .-.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200676/recursively-list-all-properties-exposed-by-a-class/22201894#22201894 , upvote if it is useful

Comment: have you thought about using JarClassLoader?

Comment: I have heard about it but, I dont know much. Ill take a look though.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question to this not too long ago. Here's the code to get all methods from a given class, I think it's fairly self-explanatory:

```
void foo(Object o)
{
    Class<?> c = o.getClass();
    for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods())
    {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the Java's Reflection API. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).