# Generic function to make post request in Volley

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, android-volley

I work on developing an android app and I would like to make a generic function of volley post request, I write my function as bellow:

```
 public fun <T> push(context: Context, url: String, myObject: T, completion: (response: String) -> Unit) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val sr = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                println(response)
                completion(response)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { volleyError ->
                Common.showVolleyError(volleyError, context)
            }) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = myObject as HashMap<String, String>
                return params
            }

            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                params["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
                return params
            }
        }

        sr.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        )
        queue.add(sr)
    }
```

What I enforce is How to convert my serializable object to a `HashMap<String, String>()`, i.e. How to bind `myObject` to `getParams()` function,

Comment: Does your api want a json body for post request?

Comment: My API receive body as  `application/x-www-form-urlencode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally for any one may like to use this way, I rewrite function as below:

```
public fun <T> push(context: Context, url: String, myObject: T,myObjectType : Array<Field>, completion: (response: String) -> Unit) {

    val myObjectAsDict = HashMap<String, String>()
    val allFields = myObjectType //:Array<Field> = myObjectType!!::class.java.declaredFields
    for ( field in allFields) {
        if (!field.isAccessible) {
            field.isAccessible = true
        }


        val value = field.get(myObject)
        if (value != null)
        {
            if( field.name != "serialVersionUID") {
                myObjectAsDict[field.name] = value.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    println(myObjectAsDict)

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val sr = object : StringRequest(
        Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            println(response)
            completion(response)
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { volleyError ->
            Common.showVolleyError(volleyError, context)
        }) {

        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = myObjectAsDict
            return params
        }

        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            params["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
            return params
        }
    }

    sr.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
        0,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    )
    queue.add(sr)
}
```

And using of it As below:

```
 var myClass = MyClass()
        VolleyFunctions.push(this,"URL",myClass, MyClass::class.java.declaredFields)
        {
                response->
            myClass = Gson().fromJson(response, MyClass::class.java)
            println("myClass.Name${myClass.name}")
        }
```

Thanks faranjit for your answer and yours comments.

Answer (score 0):

Make a base class includes an abstract method returns `Map<String, String>` named for example `getConvertedParams`. This method should convert itself to `Map<String, String>` like:

```
val params = HashMap<String, String>()
params["attribute1"] = attribute1
params["attribute2"] = attribute2
...
return params
```

Every request object should extends that base class and override that method. In `getParams` where you send request, call `getConvertedParams` for your generic request object.

```
override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
   val params = myObject.getConvertedParams()
   return params
}
```

Also do not forget to change the method signature

```
public fun <BaseClassName> push(context: Context, url: String, myObject: BaseClassName, completion: (response: String) -> Unit)
```

Comment: I know this way but I want a way to convert any serializable object to  `HashMap<String, String>()`

Comment: Have you ever looked at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024300/java-convert-instance-of-class-to-hashmap) or [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-object-to-map-example/)? If you had, didnt they work?